# How can I fix 3D viewer problem on KiCAD?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I am designing a circuit on KiCAD. I added new components to footprint with 3D models. When I open 3D viewer in footprint editor, everything looks fine however when i use the component and open 3D viewer on pcb wiindow, 3D models cannot be seen. I coudln't solve the problem. It would be nice to get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're more likely to get this answered if you post it on the kicad forums: https://forum.kicad.info/

Comment: This is a common issue. Many components from the libraries have 3D models already, but if you make your own components, they will not have 3D models.  You will have to make these yourself. The KiCAD forums are the place to learn about that. Also search for [KiCAD StepUp](https://kicad.org/external-tools/stepup/). Learning will take some time.

Comment: If you're doing it yourself, get the .STEP format 3D file from the mfg or vendor. Getting it in the appropriate directory is important. Edit footprint, Footprint Properties, I believe, and there is a 3D tab to pick the file and adjust the position and rotation of the model in space, relative to the footprint. You can also edit the footprint text file directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could happen when the 3D models are added to the footprint in the footprint editor after they are already placed on the PCB. You will need to "refresh" the footprint on the PCB for it to take effect.

In KiCAD V4, go to properties>Change footprint. Make sure the new footprint and current footprint are same and hit apply.

In KiCAD V5, right click on footprint and click on Update footprint.

If this does not work, check the settings in the 3D viewer. Preference>Display Options, make sure the 3D visibility setting are checked.